# Google Drive: Getting a Suspended users permission Id

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to map the sharing inside my Google apps domain using the Drive API.  I am able to get the users permissionId by creating a service for the user and then doing something like

```
about_info = service.about.get().execute()
permissionId = about_info['user']['permissionId']
```

However, when I iterate over one of my users that is suspended I get:

```
401 Unauthorized : Invalid Credentials
```

Is the anyway to around this for a suspended user?

Comment: How does the SDK say to indicate the permissions of a user.  Why is a suspended account still connected to your domain?

Answer (score 1):

As a non-suspended user, try [sharing a file with the suspended user](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) then [retrieve the file's permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list) to determine the suspended user's permissionId.